# How to install gprof on OS X

Tags: c++, installation, profiling, gprof

I'm trying to use gprof to profile a c++ application I've written but I can't figure out for the life of me how to download and install it. I've googled everything I can think of and can't even find a download link. Someone please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems there are two components to gprof.  One is a part of the GCC compiler itself, invoked by using the -pg argument.  The other is the gprof command, which [apparently](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils) is part of GNU binutils.  I'll leave it to you to figure out how to install GCC and binutils on OSX...

Comment: It seems that gprof does not understand Mach-O executables and therefore cannot be used to profile OS X programs.

Comment: @Mohan just do this: `mv $(type gcc) $(type gcc)-apple && brew install gcc && brew install binutils`.

Answer (score 9):

I did not find a MacOS solution for `gprof` and `gcov` did not work for me, but `gperftools` (Google Performance Tools) do work. Here is how to install them on MacOS:

```
brew install google-perftools graphviz ghostscript gv
brew link --overwrite ghostscript
```

Next, run the profiler on a program:

```
CPUPROFILE=program_name.prof DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/gperftools/2.6.3/lib/libprofiler.dylib ./program_name
pprof --pdf program_name program_name.prof > program_name.pdf
```

You can find more options for `gperftools` [here](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/cpuprofile.html). Finally, open the `program_name.pdf` file in a PDF viewer such as Preview to enjoy the fancy `graphviz` output.

Obviously, running the profiler on a program can be automated very easily with a Bash script, as there only is the one `program_name` parameter and the shared library location is constant. Here is an example script called `profile.sh` that does exactly that, but includes compiling and adds a second variable so that you can compile `.cpp` files with a different name:

```
#!/bin/bash
g++-7 -fopenmp -O3 -o $1 $2.cpp
CPUPROFILE=$1.prof DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Cellar/gperftools/2.6.3/lib/libprofiler.dylib ./$1
pprof --pdf $1 $1.prof > $1.pdf
echo "Profiling results: $1.pdf"
```

Next, modify the permissions so it can run from any folder:

```
chmod +x profile.sh
```

The script can be invoked from the command line as follows, automating the full process:

```
./profile.sh program_name cpp_name
```

You may want to separate the compilation and profiling steps, which is easy enough to do by removing the `g++-7` line in the shell script.

Comment: I had to 'brew install gv' also

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the note. Updated to include `gv`.

Comment: can simply do `brew install gperftools` now

Comment: these steps don't work for me, see https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/1292; `pprof` fails with: 
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool-classic: can't open file: /usr/lib/liboah.dylib (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 3):

Since gprof does not work on OS X at the moment, use [Google Performance Tools](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/), now known as [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools).

Also [gcov](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html) works "out of the box" if you have gcc installed.

```
$ gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage your_program.c
$ a.out
$ gcov your_program.c
```

Comment: cohadar, did you check that google perf tools (pprof + libprofiler) works on OSX? gcov is not profiling tool, it is coverage tool...

Comment: If `your_program.c` exists in a different folder of running `gcov`, it will not work. You must pass `your_program.gcno` to the `gcov` to work.